# Upload and see multiple images without rename - php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I'm using this code to upload multiple images to a path and then store this path in my database. The database table is called "images" with fields: id, name(varchar), image(longblob). I can upload them, but every time the images are stored in the path, their names change. For example, if I upload an image called "cat.png" and store it to `uploads/`directory, its name becomes something like "366331bd4c8bcb503ceda1ae229b79e0.png". Also, I cannot see the images when they are uploaded-only a broken image icon. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Upload Images</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <form action="upload_file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <p>Select Image (one or multiple):</p>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="262144000"/>
  <input type="file" name="image[]" accept="image/jpeg" accept="image/jpg" accept="image/png" accept="image/gif" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php

```html
<?php
include('../config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
 $target_path = "uploads/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++) {
  // Loop to get individual element from the array
  $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
  $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
  $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
  $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) -1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
  $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
  
  if (($_FILES["image"]["size"][$i] < 262144000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {

    $final_name = explode('/', $target_path);
    $image_name_final=$final_name[$i];
    $sql="INSERT INTO images (id,name,image) VALUES ('','$image_name_final','$target_path')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    
    // If file moved to uploads folder.
    echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
    //Show selected image(s)
    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
   } else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
    echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
    }
  } else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
    echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
   }
 }
}
error_reporting(-1);
?>
```

get.php

```html
<?php
include('../config.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);
$image = $image['image'];

header('Content-type: image/png');

echo base64_decode($image);
?>
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: `$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) -1]; ` changes the name to unique id

Comment: if you don't want uniq/changing filenames for the files, then why are you generating unique hashes each time the file's uploaded. "Everytime I stab this fork into my eye, it hurts. How do I keep my eye from hurting?"

Comment: yes, but do you know how should i fix this?

Comment: @Mark B You could be less sarcastic and more helpful you know. Clearly I have been looking on how to edit this line and since I couldn't, I asked here. Can you help or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lashane pointed out in the comments above, your code is generating a unique MD5 hash for each file. It's this line, and specifically the md5() function:

`$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) -1];`

You say you just want the files to have the same name every time. To do that, you should be able to simply write:

`$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);`

Comment: thanks a lot it works now! I also want to see the images when they are uploaded, and while this line was working when I was uploading one image, now it shows a broken image icon.  `$lastid = mysql_insert_id(); echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Without seeing the code for get.php I can't be sure

Comment: it's there, the last box :)

Comment: When you save the row into the database, the "image" field contains the target_path value...a filename. When get.php runs, it's retrieving this value and converting into base64 format. you would do this if you were trying to return the actual image content, not a link to it. You need to return the path to the image. even then, target_path may be a hard path to the file on disk (e.g. /home/user/images/x.jpg) but what you want to return is the relative path as seen by the webserver (e.g. "public_html/images/x.jpg"). This will depend on where your images are stored compared to the php file

Comment: To add to that, I just spotted in your code that target_path starts with "uploads". so that's probably ok. It's the base64 thing that is likely to be a problem. You just need to return it as a string. And also check that the file is definitely being saved into that location on disk.

Comment: Do you know how to return it as string? I tried `string base64_decode ($image); echo($image);`, but i still can't see them

Comment: what is actually being output to the browser? Can you show me the html for the img tag?

Comment: the output is the message "Image uploaded successfully!" and next to it a broken image icon

Comment: Yes, you said. That's what you see as a user, but what does the underlying HTML markup look like? you need to View Source or press F12 to get the developer tools and see what the img tag looks like